# Validating password/username issue with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI program using python that allows the user to register a username and password and then login. The issue I am encountering is that if the username is incorrect, the program will run as intended and print "User Not Found". However, even if the username is correct and the password is wrong, the program will still pop up with "Login success" when it should be "Password Error". Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def delete2():
    screen3.destroy()
    
def delete3():
    screen4.destroy()

def delete4():
    screen5.destroy()
    

def login_success():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen3.title("Error")
    screen3.geometry("150x100")
    Label(screen3, text = "Login success").pack()
    Button(screen3, text = "OK", command = delete2).pack()
    

def password_not_recognised():
    global screen4
    screen4 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen4.title("Success")
    screen4.geometry("150x100")
    Label(screen4, text = "Password Error").pack()
    Button(screen4 , text = "OK", command = delete3).pack()


def user_not_found():
    global screen5
    screen5 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen5.title("Error")
    screen5.geometry("150x100")
    Label(screen5, text = "Username Not Found").pack()
    Button(screen5 , text = "OK", command = delete4).pack()


def register_user():
    
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    file = open(username_info, "w")
    file.write(username_info+"\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(screen1, text = "Registration Success", fg = "green", font = ("calibri", 11)).pack()


def login_verify():
    
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = username_verify.get()
    username_entry1.delete(0, END)
    password_entry1.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            login_success()
        else:
            password_not_recognised()
            
    else:
        user_not_found()
    

def register():
    global screen1
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Register")
    screen1.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Username * ").pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Password * ").pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen1, text = "Register", width = 10, height = 1, command = register_user).pack()
    

def login():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry("300x250")
    Label(screen2, text = "Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify
        
    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_entry1
    global password_entry1
    
    Label(screen2, text = "Username * ").pack()
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Password * ").pack()
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Login", width = 10, height = 1, command = login_verify).pack()
    
    
def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x250")
    screen.title("Notes 1.0")
    Label(text = "Login/Register", bg = "grey", width= "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", height = "2", width = "30", command = login).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register", height = "2", width = "30", command = register).pack()

    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Do you get any error on your terminal? Such as there is no method `splitlines`? Also, worth noting that `readlines` does exist in case that's what you actually used, but preserves the new line in each string.